# Jquery xml tag is exist or not

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using Jquery and trying to find out whether below tag is exist or not

```
if(feed.mediaGroups[0].contents[0].thumbnails[0].url !== 'undefined') {
                        thumb = feed.mediaGroups[0].contents[0].thumbnails[0].url;
                    }
```

but this is crashing saying

```
TypeError: feed.mediaGroups is undefined
```

any idea ho i can get it worked.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're checking for a property a looong way down the chain, but clearly the `feed` object doesn't even have a `mediaGroups` property, so you should probably start there

```
if(
    'mediaGroups' in feed &&
    Array.isArray(feed.mediaGroups) &&
    'contents' in feed.mediaGroups[0] &&
    Array.isArray(feed.mediaGroups[0].contents) &&
    'thumbnails' in feed.mediaGroups[0].contents[0] &&
    Array.isArray(feed.mediaGroups[0].contents[0].thumbnails) &&
    'url' in feed.mediaGroups[0].contents[0].thumbnails[0] &&
    typeof feed.mediaGroups[0].contents[0].thumbnails[0].url !== 'undefined'
) {
    thumb = feed.mediaGroups[0].contents[0].thumbnails[0].url;
}
```

you can see how this gets really tedious, and we didn't even check everything, we could still check if the arrays have a value at the index `0` etc, so knowing what to expect is really helpful, and you shouldn't really have to check each and every property in this way

Comment: Thank you Adeneo.. but i am worried its too long, isn't there any short method using Jquery or javascript

Comment: No there isn't, when you have a nested object you can't just check the outer most property if you don't know if all the properties you're using are defined, you have to check each property that could potentially be undefined, and that's why it helps to know what you're expecting, and to check for that only, and not everything. You probably could use a try/catch to catch the error, but that's even worse and shouldn't be done.